How to register JsonConverters in an extension method for WebApi Controllers?
I have a DDD style project where Program.cs references different projects and then calls extension methods in which those projects register their dependencies on their own
TL:DR; How do I register a JsonConverter from an extension method so that it gets used in my WebApi responses (without referencing MVC packages)?
I understand I can add them during setup at the AddControllers call like so for example
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x =>
{
    x.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new SomeCustomConverter());
});

But I have some very specific converters in another project which does not have access to MVC references.
So what I usually do is that I just call the extension methods in my startup class like so
// ...
builder.Services.AddApplicationLayer();
// ...

and in my application layer project I have an extension method that registers its dependencies
public static class DependencyInjection
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddApplicationLayer(this IServiceCollection services) => services
        .AddScoped<IFoo, Foo>()
        // .. and so on
}

One of my services is serializing interfaces. That's why we use custom JsonConverters to make sure that each items gets serialized with the properties of it's actual type
An example data structure
public interface IAlias
{
    string Id { get; }
    AliasKind Kind { get; }
}

public sealed record FooAlias(string Id, Guid? TypeId) : IAlias
{
    public AliasKind Kind => AliasKind.Foo;
}

public sealed record BarAlias(string Id, Guid TargetTypeId) : IAlias
{
    public AliasKind Kind => AliasKind.Relationship;
}

// ..


We then serialize a List<IAlias> and w/o converter it just gets serialized as IAlias which looks like this { "id": "..", "kind": "Foo" }. A converter takes care that it gets read and write as it's actualy type.

I ended up using an extension method on JsonSerializerOptions. I don't like this approach too much but it gets the job done w/o requiring any further mvc dependencies
// the usual extension method I use to register dependencies within other projects
builder.Services.AddApplicationLayer(); 
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x =>
{
    // the new extension method
    x.JsonSerializerOptions.AddApplicationLayer(); 
});

// ...

public static JsonSerializerOptions AddApplicationLayer(this JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
   options.Converters.Add(...);

   return options;
}


Not sure, but from what I understand, you can simply implement adding the onverter in extension method you already have:
public static class DependencyInjection
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddApplicationLayer(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x =>
        {
            x.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new SomeCustomConverter());
        });

        services
            .AddScoped<IFoo, Foo>()
        // .. and so on

        return services;
    }
}

Alternatively, you can define extension method for IMvcBuilder, which will encapsulate all your converters' registration:
public static class MvcBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IMvcBuilder AddJsonConverters(this IMvcBuilder mvcBuilder)
    {
        return mvcBuilder.AddJsonOptions(x =>
        {
            x.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new SomeCustomConverter());
        });
    }
}

and then use like:
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonConverters();


Thanks for your response. But afaik that'd require my application layer include a reference to the MVC package, right?

@boop yes, you need to add <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" /> to your project file. See this article

That's the whole point. I don't want to add these kind of references to my business logic layer
